# concat specifc fields from Java POJO and store it as key, and store the object as value in HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap, pojo

I am new to Java.
I have a  Java POJO in an ArrayList.
I would like to concatenate some specific fields of that POJO into a String and store the value as key and the object itself as value in a Hash Map.
I don't want to concatenate all the fields, just specific fields.
The Java classes have been generated at run time from Json schema using a library.So declaring a method in POJO wont work as there are 100's of classes.
I can get the class at run time. I can also get the fields at run time. I want to write a generic function where I pass the object and the function will return all the concatenated fields of that object.

Answer (score 0):

In your POJO, declare a method

```
public void getKey(){

    return fielda + fieldb + fieldc;
}
```

and that method should return a concatenated string of those fields

and you get then add to your map

```
map.put(pojo.getKey(), pojo);
```

---

You can also do it like this(without a getKey method):

```
String key = pojo.getField1 + pojo.getField2 + pojo.getFiel3;

map.put(key, pojo)
```

Comment: The Java classes have been generated in run time from Json schema using a library.So declaring a method in POJO wont work. Any other option?

Comment: I added another example for you in my answer.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer, but since there are 100's of classes having different fields, I can't do a get Field as the name s of the fields will be different for every class.

Comment: so then how do you expect to create a key from fields if you don't know which fields you want to use?

Comment: there must be a different solution. why do you need those keys?

Comment: anyways, how can you use the class if you don't know which fields they have?

Comment: I can get the class at run time. I can also get the fields at run time. I want to write a generic function where I pass the object and the function will return all the concatenated fields of that object.

Comment: in your question you stated that you don't want all fields, only some specific fields as the key.

Comment: I figured it out. Used java reflection to get the fields. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Override `getKey()` method of that class .

Say you have one class employee

```
Class Employee{
    private int empId;
private String firstname;
private String lastname;
private String city;
private String areaCode;


public void getKey(){
return this.empid+this.areaCode;
}
```

}

You can now call this method to generate the required key and add it into Hashmap.

```
HashMap<String,Employee> list= new HashMap<String,Employee>
list.add(emp.getKey(),emp);
```

Comment: The Java classes have been generated in run time from Json schema using a library.So declaring a method in POJO wont work. Any other option?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using stream.

```
    class POJO {
        private String field1;
        private String field2;
        private String field3;

        public POJO(String field1, String field2, String field3) {
            this.field1 = field1;
            this.field2 = field2;
            this.field3 = field3;
        }
    }

    List<POJO> list = Arrays.asList(
            new POJO("f11", "f12", "f13"),
            new POJO("f11", "f12", "f23"),
            new POJO("f31", "f32", "f33")
    );
    // below is all you need
    Map<String, POJO> map = list.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(
            pojo -> pojo.field1 + pojo.field2, // construct the key using pojo fields
            pojo -> pojo,                      // store pojo as value
            (pojo1, pojo2) -> pojo1            // if 2 pojos have the same key, which one you would like to keep
    ));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can probably wrap your original POJOs with anonymous class, whose only responsibility would be properly implement `equals/hashCode` contract. Something like this (simplified):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    A a1 = new A("John", 33);
    A a2 = new A("April", 25);
    Map<AKey, A> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put(key(a1), a1);
    map.put(key(a2), a2);
    A a3 = new A("John", 28);
    map.put(key(a3), a3);
    System.out.println(map);
}

interface AKey {
    String getKey();
}

static AKey key(final A a)
{
    return new AKey() {
        @Override public String getKey() { return a.name; }

        @Override public int hashCode() { return getKey().hashCode(); }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            return Objects.equals(getKey(), ((AKey)obj).getKey());
        }

        @Override public String toString() { return getKey(); }
    };
}

static class A
{
    public String name;
    public int age;

    public A(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "A{" + "name='" + name + '\'' + ", age=" + age + '}';
    }
}
```